# Discord.py Slap Commmand

Tags: python, discord.py

I am here with an annoying error when I use this code. I use this code for other commands like slap, hug, kiss, etc. I reuse this code a lot and it seems like the more I put the more errors I get...

Code:

```py
@client.command()
async def feed(ctx, member:discord.User=None):
  feedGIF = [    
    "https://i.imgur.com/1vC0R20.gif",
    "https://data.whicdn.com/images/81561319/original.gif",
    "https://thumbs.gfycat.com/EagerSpectacularHoverfly-max-14mb.gif",
    "https://64.media.tumblr.com/4d160635539ef31d8b058bc3e35a907c/tumblr_p4e113SOw91wn2b96o1_400.gifv",
    "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7a/cb/20/7acb209c594f42e0d56b87d70421c85d.gif",
  ]  

  feedSelfResponse = [
    f"{ctx.author.mention} feeds them selves. So eating?",
    f"{ctx.author.mention} feeds themselves yum!",
    f"{ctx.author.mention} is feeding their hungry stomach",
    f"{ctx.author.mention} is being fed by... themselves",
  ]
  feedResponse = [ 
    f"{ctx.author.mention} feeds {member.mention}",
    f"{member.mention} is being feed by {ctx.member.mention}. Open wide!",
    f"Yum! {ctx.member.mention} feeds {member.mention}. Here comes the airplane!",    
  ]  
  if (member == ctx.message.author or member == None):
    feed = f"{random.choice(feedSelfResponse)}"
  else:
    feed = f"{random.choice(feedResponse)}"

  embed = discord.Embed(color=0x9b59b6)
  embed.set_image(url=f"{random.choice(feedGIF)}")
  embed.add_field(name="Feed", value=(feed))
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'member'
```

I have no idea how to fix this please help!

Comment: You’ve used ctx.author everywhere but then you decided to use ctx.member? That doesn’t really make sense...

Comment: Oh! That was a typo... Sorry about that.

Comment: Well yeah that was the error

Comment: Nope. I fixed it and when you use the command on yourself if gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I have fixed your command

```
import random

@client.command()
async def feed(ctx, member:discord.Member = None):
    feedGIF = [    
        "https://i.imgur.com/1vC0R20.gif",
        "https://data.whicdn.com/images/81561319/original.gif",
        "https://thumbs.gfycat.com/EagerSpectacularHoverfly-max-14mb.gif",
        "https://64.media.tumblr.com/4d160635539ef31d8b058bc3e35a907c/tumblr_p4e113SOw91wn2b96o1_400.gifv",
        "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7a/cb/20/7acb209c594f42e0d56b87d70421c85d.gif",
    ]  

    if (member == ctx.author or member == None):
        feedSelfResponse = [
            f"{ctx.author.mention} feeds them selves. So eating?",
            f"{ctx.author.mention} feeds themselves yum!",
            f"{ctx.author.mention} is feeding their hungry stomach",
            f"{ctx.author.mention} is being fed by... themselves",
        ]
        feed = random.choice(feedSelfResponse)
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x9b59b6)
        embed.set_image(url=random.choice(feedGIF))
        embed.add_field(name="Feed", value=(feed))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        feedResponse = [ 
            f"{ctx.author.mention} feeds {member.mention}",
            f"{member.mention} is being feed by {ctx.author.mention}. Open wide!",
            f"Yum! {ctx.author.mention} feeds {member.mention}. Here comes the airplane!",    
        ]  
        feed = random.choice(feedResponse)
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x9b59b6)
        embed.set_image(url=random.choice(feedGIF))
        embed.add_field(name="Feed", value=(feed))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I'm thinking the error was that Python reads the command from top to bottom so it tried to fill the the `{ctx.author.mention}`, but the member = None.